# Many to many relationship when order metter

Tags: sql, sqlite, many-to-many, android-sqlite, sql-order-by

I have many to many relation between User and Group: group may contains few users and consists in multiply groups.
Server send me json like this, and I need to store it to DB:

```
group: {
  name: "test", id: "UUID"
  users: [
    {name: "user1", id: "UUID"}, 
    {name: "user2", id: "UUID"}, 
    {name: "user3", id: "UUID"} 
  ]
}
```

**The problem is:** users order in group matters - users should be displayed in the same order like in servers json.
The fist solution that I use is add to group field like 
`user_ids: [user1_uuid, user2_uuid, user3_uuid]` and store it into DB in json fromat, but I see 2 problems in this solution:

1. It contradicts to first normal form (1NF)
2. When I SELECT values they have wrong order:

`SELECT * FROM user WHERE id IN (:user_ids)`

How to store it into DB and SELECT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, table rows indeed are unordered; the only guaranteed way to get ordered rows is to use ORDER BY.

If the order of your array elements is important, add a column for the array index.

Comment: Could you provide an example, please?

Comment: What exactly do you want to see? How to add a column? How to write ORDER BY?

Comment: I want to see DB structure. For me is unclear in what table to add column. For example I can't add it to `user` table cause in 1 group this user can be in 1 place and in another group it can be in the other place

Comment: So you have an M:N relationship between users and groups? How do you implement that in your database?

Comment: I use additional table `group_user` with columns `group_id` and `user_id` and `_id autoincrement`.

Comment: As far as I understand your proposition is to add to this `group_user` new column `order` and store there array indexes?

Comment: Yes, it is the user/group connections that you want to order. (You probably do not need the `_id` column, and `order` is an SQL keyword.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE user(id integer primary key, name text);
CREATE TABLE grp(id integer primary key, name text);
CREATE TABLE usergrp(userid integer, grpid integer, position integer);
CREATE INDEX positionindex on usergrp(grpid, position);
```

Then you can retrieve users belonging to a group with the query

```
SELECT userid FROM usergrp WHERE grpid=? ORDER BY position;
```

Also, maybe you would like to use the  ["without rowid"](https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) sqlite table storage option for usergrp.